# How can I animate reputation changes in Stack Exchange?

Tags: animation, shotcut

I'm making a YouTube video on discrimination, and among other things I'll explain [this study](https://static1.squarespace.com/static/57967bc7cd0f68048126361d/t/5cdf2d4c7d1b310001d046fc/1558129997622/BohrenImasRosenberg_DynamicsDiscrimination_January2019.pdf) which shows anti-female bias against new female StackExchange users, but pro-female bias toward experienced female StackExchange users (i.e. high reputation users with female usernames).

I'm thinking of animating it using the below picture, where the user upvotes Bruce's question, and Bruce's reputation increases to 11. Thereafter the reputation of both rapidly increases to 1000 (i.e. both become high reputation users). And then Emily receives an upvote, bringing her reputation to 1010.

[image]

How can I do so? I am using ShotCut. After doing some internet searches, I think the [timer filter](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=m4nSFkyLvJU) can be used to animate the reputation increase, but I'm not so sure how to animate user clicks short of manually creating a HTML/Javascript page and then recording my screen. Most of the videos on animating user clicks in ShotCut explain how to add pre-recorded "click on YouTube subscribe" buttons to one's video.

Comment: While the context is interesting, in essence you're looking for two things: 1) animate a user clicking a button and 2) animate an (increasing) number counter. If you do a web-search for both ([button](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+animate+rapidly+increasing+number+counter), [counter](https://duckduckgo.com/?q=how+to+create+animation+clicking+button+in+video)), what methods did you find? What issues did you encounter? Please edit your question to include these things.

Comment: The reason I ask, is because someone could write a whole answer, only to find that you've looked into that already and that didn't work for your because of certain reasons (e.g. no after effects, technique does not work for your case, etc...).

Comment: I completely forgot/didn't realize the points you mentioned. Just edited my question. Many thanks, @SaaruLindestøkke